# Eloquent fetch User Posts "with()" COUNT of their Ratings (1-5)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a problem with Laravel's Eloquent.

I have:

```
Users (hasMany(Posts))
Posts (hasMany(Ratings))
Ratings (belongsTo(Post)
    - has "rating_value" of 1-5
```

I need to fetch all posts created by a user, and also get the count of the rating_value (1-5) present in the third table "ratings", so that I can show the user how many others have rated each rating_value.

```
Eg view of users own posts:
    Post 1: 30 (other users) rated +1, 50 rated +2, ... etc. up to "rated +5".
    Post 2: ... 
    ...
```

**The code where I hope experienced Eloquenters will see the problem...**

```
private function fetchUserPosts($request) {
    $this -> userPosts
        = $this -> user
        -> posts()
        -> with([
            'ratings' => function ($query) {
                $query -> selectRaw('post_id, rating_value, count(*) AS count')
                    -> groupBy('rating_value');
            }
        ])
        -> get();
}
```

So I do get all posts, but the problem is that for ONE of the results I get the count of that rating-value, for all posts, NOT for that particular Post that I thought I was querying using the "$query"?

So when three posts should have 1 rating of "+1" each, one of them shows to have all those "+1"-ratings, and the others come back empty.

I don't understand why?

Partial (stripped) response:

```
    "userPosts": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 2,
        "ratings": [] // SHOULD have "rating_value": 1, "count": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "user_id": 2,
        "ratings": [] // SHOULD have "rating_value": 1, "count": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "user_id": 2,
        "ratings": [
            {
                "post_id": 4,
                "rating_value": 2,
                "count": 1 // This works fine as there is only one post by this user that anyone rated 2, but then it gets messed up...
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "user_id": 2,
        "ratings": [
            {
                "post_id": 5,
                "rating_value": 1,
                "count": 3
            }
        ]
    },
 
// To clearify the following lines are added manually to show how it would look with a real, larger user base:
 
    {
        "id": 6,
        "user_id": 2,
        "ratings": [
            {
                "post_id": 6,
                "rating_value": 1,
                "count": 25
            }, 
            {
                "post_id": 6,
                "rating_value": 2,
                "count": 102
            }, 
            {
                "post_id": 6,
                "rating_value": 3,
                "count": 509
            }, 
            {
                "post_id": 6,
                "rating_value": 4,
                "count": 204
            }, 
            {
                "post_id": 6,
                "rating_value": 5,
                "count": 57
            }
        ]
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alexey Mezenins answer I ended up solving the problem like this:

```
private function fetchUserPosts($request) {

    $userPosts = $this->user->posts()->with('ratings')->get();

    $this -> userPosts = $userPosts -> map(function ($item) {

        $item -> ratingCounts = new \stdClass();

        $item -> ratingCounts -> veryPositive = $item -> ratings -> where('rating_value', 5) -> count();
        $item -> ratingCounts -> positive = $item -> ratings -> where('rating_value', 4) -> count();
        $item -> ratingCounts -> neutral = $item -> ratings -> where('rating_value', 3) -> count();
        $item -> ratingCounts -> negative = $item -> ratings -> where('rating_value', 2) -> count();
        $item -> ratingCounts -> veryNegative = $item -> ratings -> where('rating_value', 1) -> count();

        // To not return raw rating-rows that includes rating users id etc... 
        unset($item -> ratings);

        return $item;
    });

}
```

By all means tell me if there are any problems with it!

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data:

```
$this->userPosts = $this->user->posts()->with('ratings')->get();
```

And use [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-map) and [`count()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-count) collection methods to create a new property with counted ratings:

```
$this->userPosts = $this->userPosts->map(function ($item) {
    for ($i = 1; $ <= 5; $i++) {
        $item->rating{$i} = $item->ratings->where('rating_value', $i)->count();
    }

    return $item;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great info for a novice like myself! But, I don't need the rating sum, as rating 1/2/3/4/5 is just a type of rating, and not supposed to mean anything itself. What I need is the count of how Many of these there are.

Comment: @Fredrik please read **update** section of my answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Well we're getting there I guess, but I need the count for each type of rating_value. So for rating value 1 there are x ratings) / for 2 there are y ratings etc. / 3 / 4 / 5 ). Please see the example furthest down in the response I provided for an example of how I'd like the data to be served.

Comment: There were a few problems with this, but in theory I like the solution. Mapping was the key here. Look at my own answer to see how I did in the end. Thanks for the help, and I left you an upvote but I need some more rep first it seems! 

Btw, should I accept my own or you answer in this case?